# XHTML 1.0 Strict Validation Error

Tags: validation, xhtml

I got 2 errors when validating my XHTML strict input type below:

```
<form action="" method="post" id="frm">
   <input type="text" id="searchtext" name="search" value="Suchen" />
   <input type="image" id="searchbutton" name="search" src="images/search-icon.png" />
</form>
```

The errors are:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens if you try to put an input directly into a form without a container element, and validate under XHTML 1.0 strict. Put it into a div, and it goes away.

Refer: [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5865963/w3c-validator-gives-document-type-does-not-allow-element-input-here-error)

[why it happens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982590/strict-doctype-form-and-input-element)