# <select> not allowed in <form> tag?

Tags: html, forms, validation, drop-down-menu, xhtml-1.0-strict

I'm in the process of cleaning up a website's code. One of the things I am doing is running each page's code through the W3C Markup Validation Service: https://validator.w3.org/

For the page I'm currently working on, the validator gave me a lot of errors. I have already fixed nearly all of them but there is one error I can't figure out:
`Line 92, Column 108: document type does not allow element "select" here; missing one of "p", "h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", "h6", "div", "pre", "address", "fieldset", "ins", "del" start-tag`

The section of code that is giving me this error is here (line 92 is the one starting with `select size="1"` and column 108 appears to be just before the fullstop right after `Pageselector`):

```
<div style="text-align:center;">
    <form id="Pageselector" action="">
        <select size="1" name="FC" onchange="location.href=Pageselector.FC.options[selectedIndex].value">
            <option selected="selected">Go to Page...</option>
            <option value="AC_1.html">Page 1: Introduction</option>
            <option value="AC_2.html">Page 2: Essential Optimization</option>
            <option value="AC_3.html">Page 3: Troubleshooting Tips</option>
            <option value="AC_4.html">Page 4: Patches &amp; Mods</option>
            <option value="AC_5.html">Page 5: In-Game Settings</option>
            <option value="AC_6.html">Page 6: In-Game Settings (Pt.2)</option>
            <option value="AC_7.html">Page 7: In-Game Settings (Pt.3)</option>
            <option value="AC_8.html">Page 8: Advanced Tweaking</option>
            <option value="AC_9.html">Page 9: Adv. Tweaking (Pt.2)</option>
            <option value="AC_10.html">Page 10: Neat Stuff &amp; Concl.</option>
        </select>
    </form>
</div>
```

The code in question is a drop down list that lets you select which web page in the series you want to look at. After choosing an option, the browser opens the selected page. I don't understand what the problem is because according to w3schools, the `select` element is allowed to be inside a `form` element: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_form.asp

If you need to see all the code on the page or need anything else, you can say so and I will edit this question. The DocType I am using is `XHTML 1.0 Strict`. The code above does do what it is supposed to. I'm just trying to clean and refactor it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some more digging and found the answer. First, I tested changing the page's DocType from `Strict` to `Transitional` then re-validating. This made the error disappear. I then did some searching and found this question: [Strict doctype - form and input element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982590/strict-doctype-form-and-input-element)

It seems that `Strict` DocTypes do not allow you to have an `Input` (or `Select`) element as a direct descendant of a `Form` element. The direct descendant has to be one of the elements listed in the error message. With this knowledge, I have managed to get rid of the error message.

To fix it, I changed the code to the following (I just swapped around the `Form` and `Div` elements, and included wazz's suggestion):

```
<form id="Pageselector" action="">
    <div style="text-align:center;">
        <select size="1" name="FC" onchange="location.href = this.options[selectedIndex].value">
            <option selected="selected">Go to Page...</option>
            <option value="AC_1.html">Page 1: Introduction</option>
            <option value="AC_2.html">Page 2: Essential Optimization</option>
            <option value="AC_3.html">Page 3: Troubleshooting Tips</option>
            <option value="AC_4.html">Page 4: Patches &amp; Mods</option>
            <option value="AC_5.html">Page 5: In-Game Settings</option>
            <option value="AC_6.html">Page 6: In-Game Settings (Pt.2)</option>
            <option value="AC_7.html">Page 7: In-Game Settings (Pt.3)</option>
            <option value="AC_8.html">Page 8: Advanced Tweaking</option>
            <option value="AC_9.html">Page 9: Adv. Tweaking (Pt.2)</option>
            <option value="AC_10.html">Page 10: Neat Stuff &amp; Concl.</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</form>
```

Edit: As per the comment below, you can use this code as well (added a `fieldset` tag):

```
<div style="text-align:center;">
    <form id="Pageselector" action="">
        <fieldset style="margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; border: 0px;">
            <select size="1" name="FC" onchange="location.href = this.options[selectedIndex].value">
                <option selected="selected">Go to Page...</option>
                <option value="AC_1.html">Page 1: Introduction</option>
                <option value="AC_2.html">Page 2: Essential Optimization</option>
                <option value="AC_3.html">Page 3: Troubleshooting Tips</option>
                <option value="AC_4.html">Page 4: Patches &amp; Mods</option>
                <option value="AC_5.html">Page 5: In-Game Settings</option>
                <option value="AC_6.html">Page 6: In-Game Settings (Pt.2)</option>
                <option value="AC_7.html">Page 7: In-Game Settings (Pt.3)</option>
                <option value="AC_8.html">Page 8: Advanced Tweaking</option>
                <option value="AC_9.html">Page 9: Adv. Tweaking (Pt.2)</option>
                <option value="AC_10.html">Page 10: Neat Stuff &amp; Concl.</option>
            </select>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: `<div>` is one option. `<fieldset>` might be another. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset

Comment: @RouninsaysJesuisMonica True, and the documentation seems to imply that `fieldset` is the intended way of encapsulating those elements.

Comment: Note that changing the DOCTYPE to HTML5 is another option which doesn't involve altering the content.

Comment: @MrLister That is an option but HTML5 creates other validation errors which would have to be fixed. It also doesn't have the browser backwards compatibility of XHTML 1.0. There is also the matter that, even now to my knowledge, most browsers haven't fully implemented HTML5. That said, I am running these pages through an HTML5 validater as well and fixing whatever issues I can.

Comment: @XJDHDR I hear you. It's a shame that HTML5 has changed so much from previous versions that it's impossible to have a document that satisfies both validators simultaneously now.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure the problem's not the form. I don't think you can just say `Pageselector.FC` out of the blue; that doesn't select an html element properly. Try using `this` instead. Or better yet, move the whole thing to a JS function.

```
<select size="1" name="FC" onchange="location.href = this.options[selectedIndex].value">
```

`this` refers to the element that `this` is a part of - the select element.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I found that the error was, in fact, caused by how the previous coder used the `form` element. As for `this`, using your suggested edit seems to still work. As for moving it into a JS function, I know very little about JavaScript. I would have to do some research to make that happen. In fact, I have no idea what `Pageselector.FC` does and can't seem to find any info on it.

Comment: When you put the div inside the form, does the `onchange` work as originally posted? Curious. Please vote for answers that helped.

Comment: As for voting, I would do so but Stack Exchange requires that I wait 24 hours before accepting my own answers.